# R :: How to find if any letters exist in an factor variable

Tags: r

I have an factor variable in a data table with values as below :

```
TC02345,TC02734,TS3234,34566,79800,.....
```

I need to concatenate "S" only for those records which has no letters at the beginning. (i.e) 34566,79800.

So final expected output needs to be as below :

```
TC02345,TC02734,TS3234,S37666,S778800.
```

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
df <- data.frame(my_factor = c('TC02345','TC02734','TS3234','34566','79800'))
```

Using a [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) approach, i.e. with the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages:

```
df %>%
    mutate(my_factor = str_replace(my_factor, '^(?=[0-9])', 'C'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **stringr** package.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(df$my_factor, "(^[:digit:])","S\\1")


"TC02345" "TC02734" "TS3234"  "S34566"  "S79800"
```